# Send email to multiple recipients from txt file using PHP Swiftmailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I have been working on a script to send emails using Swiftmailer to a list of recipients stored in txt file. It is supposed to take emails from `./receivers` folder all of them named `TH001.txt, TH002.txt`,... . When I run the code it goes to infinite loop with error:

```
"
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 0
 in /var/www/sipnati/sendmail.php on line 37
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 0
 in /var/www/sipnati/sendmail.php on line 37
"
```

It looks like I have messed up something with parsing the names of the files in `./receivers` 
folder. I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04 with PHP5.3 . I am completely stuck, any help pointing the mistake will be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php

require_once 'swift_required.php';

define("SMTP_SERVER", "xxx");
define("FROM_NAME", "xxx");
define("FROM_EMAIL", "xxx");
define("USERNAME", "xxx");
define("PASSWORD", "xxx");



define("LOG_PATH", "./");

class sendMail {

    public function sendMail() {

        $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(SMTP_SERVER, 25)
            ->setUsername(USERNAME)
            ->setPassword(PASSWORD)
            ;

        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);


 /*     $counter = file_get_contents("./variables.txt");
        $emails_to_send = $counter + 200;
        $file_counter = file_get_contents("./variables1.txt"); */

        $scan=array_values(array_diff(scandir('./receivers/'), array('..', '.','.htaccess')));
        $mails=array();
        $c=count($scan);
        if(isset($scan[0])){
            for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
                if(substr($scan[$i], strlen($scan[$i] - 3), 3) <> "txt"){
                    $tmp=file('./receivers/'.$scan[$i],FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
                    $mails=array_merge($mails,$tmp);
                }
            }
        }
 /*     file_put_contents("./variables1.txt", $count-1); */
        $regexp = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/';

        $count = 0;
        if($c>0){
            foreach ($mails as $key => $value) {
                while ($count < count($mails)) { /* replaced $counter with count($mails) */

                    if (preg_match($regexp, $value) != 0) {

                        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
                            ->setFrom(array(FROM_EMAIL => FROM_NAME))
                            ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
                            ->setSubject(file_get_contents('./thailand_subject.txt'))
                            ->setBody(file_get_contents('./thailand_body.txt'))
                            ;

                        if ($mailer->send($message)) {
                            $count++;
                        } else {
                            $not_sent[] = $value;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $not_sent[] = $value;
                    }
                    $count++;
                }
                /*file_put_contents("./variables.txt", $file_counter++);*/
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isset($not_sent))
            $not_sent = null;
        $this->logToFile($count, count($mails), $not_sent);
    }

    private function logToFile($count, $on, $undelivered = null) {
        $toLog = "Sent " . $count . "/" . $on . " mails. Not sent: \n" . print_r($undelivered, true);
        file_put_contents(LOG_PATH . "MAIL_LOG_" . microtime(), $toLog);
    }

}

$p = new sendMail();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, my script root folder structure is:
./receivers
  ./receivers/TH001.txt (have emails listed one below other)
  ./receivers/TH002.txt
./sendmail.php (above script)
./variables.txt (contains value 0)
./variables1.txt (contains value 0)

Hope this is what you were asking for.

Comment: print_r ($files) gives:
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => TH001.txt
    [3] => TH002.txt
)

Comment: Change  `$files[] = scandir('./receivers/'); ` with `$files[] = array_values(array_diff(scandir('./receivers/'), array('..', '.','.htaccess')));`

Comment: you are a genius, thank you very much for help. i have tested your solution and it works perfectly, apart it sends hundreds of emails to same reshipment :) will need to find why now and im good.

Comment: Basically you should check `->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))` the problem is that it's always the same

Comment: You should definitely divide this one method into multiple procedures.  This way you get a huge increase of readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New code:

```
<?php

require_once 'swift_required.php';

define("SMTP_SERVER", "xxx");
define("FROM_NAME", "xxx");
define("FROM_EMAIL", "xxx");
define("USERNAME", "xxx");
define("PASSWORD", "xxx");

define("LOG_PATH", "./");

class sendMail {

    public function sendMail() {

        $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(SMTP_SERVER, 25)
            ->setUsername(USERNAME)
            ->setPassword(PASSWORD)
            ;

        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

        $scan=array_values(array_diff(scandir('./receivers/'), array('..', '.','.htaccess')));
        $mails=array();
        $c=count($scan);
        if(isset($scan[0])){
            for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
                if(substr($scan[$i], strlen($scan[$i] - 3), 3) <> "txt"){
                    $tmp=file('./receivers/'.$scan[$i],FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
                    $mails=array_merge($mails,$tmp);
                }
            }
        }

        $regexp = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/';

        $c=count($mails);
        if($c>0){
            for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
                if (preg_match($regexp, $mails[$i]) != 0) {
                    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
                        ->setFrom(array(FROM_EMAIL => FROM_NAME))
                        ->setTo($mails[$i])
                        ->setSubject(file_get_contents('./thailand_subject.txt'))
                        ->setBody(file_get_contents('./thailand_body.txt'))
                    ;
                    if (!$mailer->send($message))
                        $not_sent[] = $mails[$i];
                }
                else
                    $not_sent[] = $mails[$i];
            }
        }
        if (!isset($not_sent))
            $not_sent = array();

        $this->logToFile($c, $not_sent);
    }

    private function logToFile($on, $undelivered) {
        $sent=$on-count($undelivered);
        $toLog = "Sent " . $sent . "/" . $on . " mails. Not sent: \n" . print_r($undelivered, true);
        file_put_contents(LOG_PATH . "MAIL_LOG_" . microtime(), $toLog);
    }

}

$p = new sendMail();
?>
```

Comment: with this update its not giving any errors, but also not sending any emails.

Comment: already removed $scan=,
print of $c gives 0
print of $mails gives ( )
i have put print_r($mails) before the foreach loop

also $scan is not defined.

Comment: it is obsolete, i have created it because i have intended to use multiple different languages and email input files.

Comment: i have edited my post with reviewed code, but unfortunately by accident i have edited your answer as well :/

First part that puts email addresses to array works perfectly now.

Comment: don't use `count()` inside a loop, because it have to count numbers each time, so isn't performant

Comment: @user1695182 Added new Code, please clean your comment, so they don't become too long